# pandas extracting data from sqlite with specific structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have an sqlite database which contains some machine information during 8736 hours. Its structure is like:

> Id Machine - Hour - ValueA - ValueB
>
> MACHDUMMY1 -  01  -   10   -    5
>
> MACHDUMMY1 -  02  -    9   -    5
>
> ..........    ..      ..        .
>
> MACHDUMMY1 - 8736 -   10   -  3.25
>
> MACHDUMMY2 -  01  -   25   -  2.12
>
> MACHDUMMY2 -  02  - 5.23   -  1.14
>
> ..........    ..      ..        .
>
> MACHDUMMY2 - 8736 -  7.8   -  17.4

How can i get the `pandas.timeseries` contain the values A for all the machines during the 8736 hours? I know how to plot the timeseries, but i don't know how to handle my data.

Someone has an idea? Or can give me some advice?

Thank you!

---- EDIT: Clarification asked ----

Ok if I do pandas.dataFrame.from_records() I will get all the informations like in my database but in my pandas.dataframe object.

But then, how can I agglomerate data from my dataframe for plotting "ValueA" where "idMachine == MachDummy1" for the 8736 hours ? In my mind I have to create a pandas.timeseries from the value, but you had probably a better idea..

Answer (score 0):

You break down the task into simple steps:

1. Load data from [a sqlite database in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).
2. [Make a pandas dataframe from the rows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html). E.g. `pandas.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=['machine_id','hour','value_a','value_b'])`.
3. [Plot the data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization.html).

Comment: You can use `pandas.read_sql(query, connection)` to do this directly

Comment: Yeah, of course not, but I meant for steps 1-2 to do it without the `from_record(cursor.fetchall() , ...)`